# How to add users and reviewers in Gerrit code review web UI

Tags: gerrit, webui

I have installed gerrit with http auth type. now i want to add reviewers and users to it.
How can i add users?

I have tried using gerrit web ui to add users. no no response from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we are using auth type as http, we need to add users/ reviewers through command line.

cat ~/.ssh/id_watcher.pub | ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit create-account --group "'Non-Interactive Users'" --ssh-key - watcher

where watcher is the username and Non-Interactive Users is group name.